# DHTMLXGantt and Laravel - Data doesn't display in extended templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dhtmlx

**Background**

Following this tutorial from Jan 2016, ( https://dhtmlx.com/blog/using-dhtmlxgantt-with-laravel/ ) I began experimenting with DHTMLXGantt (v4.1) and Laravel (v5.4) and ran into some troubles getting the sample data from a mysql/mariadb database to display in the gantt chart. The initial troubles had to do with the DHTMLX connector not staying current with some Laravel changes. For the sake of others who may read this and are struggling with the same issues, the two basic problems I already solved were:

(1) I was referred to this [updated] connector which was compatible with Laravel's recent versions ( https://github.com/mperednya/connector-php/tree/modern ). And,

(2) I specified a date range that matched the dates of the sample data (from 2013), such as...

```
gantt.config.start_date = new Date(2013, 04, 01);
gantt.config.end_date = new Date(2013, 04, 30);
```

At this point I was able to successfully use Laravel as a backend server for the DHTMLXGantt chart (including read-write with the sample data).

**Problem**

The problem I am having now is trying to move from the simplistic sample, to something slightly more complex. Specifically, when I employ Laravel's extended templating I get the gantt chart painted on screen, but no project/task data displays in the chart.

To explain this a little more specifically, a simple Laravel view with the whole page contained within it works as expected. For example, this blade file (gantt.blade.php) works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codebase/skins/dhtmlxgantt_skyblue.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Placeholder Header</h1>
    <div id="gantt_here" style='width:100%; height:500px;'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
        gantt.config.step = 1;
        gantt.config.scale_unit= "week";
        gantt.config.autosize = "xy";
        gantt.config.fit_tasks = true;

        gantt.config.columns = [
            {name:"text",       label:"Task name",  width:"*", tree:true },
            {name:"start_date", label:"Start time", align: "center" },
            {name:"duration",   label:"Duration",   align: "center" },
            {name:"add",        label:"",           width:44 }
        ];

        gantt.init("gantt_here");
        gantt.load("./gantt_data", "xml");
        var dp = new gantt.dataProcessor("./gantt_data");
        dp.init(gantt);
    </script>
    <h1>Placeholder Footer</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

But if I try using an extended app layout with the intention of building out a standard look & feel across all pages, the Gantt chart appears and is formated as I expect, but no data appears within the gantt chart. Here is top-level layout file (app.blade.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codebase/skins/dhtmlxgantt_skyblue.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
    <script src="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <!-- menus and other bootstrap styling removed for brevity -->
    @yield('content')
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the "content" view (index.blade.php)...

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div id="gantt_here" style='width:100%; height:500px;'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
        gantt.config.step = 1;
        gantt.config.scale_unit= "week";
        gantt.config.autosize = "xy";
        gantt.config.fit_tasks = true;

        gantt.config.columns = [
            {name:"text",       label:"Task name",  width:"*", tree:true },
            {name:"start_date", label:"Start time", align: "center" },
            {name:"duration",   label:"Duration",   align: "center" },
            {name:"add",        label:"",           width:44 }
            ];

        gantt.init("gantt_here");
        gantt.load("./gantt_data", "xml");
        var dp = new gantt.dataProcessor("./gantt_data");
        dp.init(gantt);
    </script>
</div>
@endsection
```

Other things I've tried:

Using Chrome developer tools, I can see that the xml data was properly delivered to the browser in both examples. This made me think maybe it is a timing problem of some sort. So I put a couple links on the page just to test clearing the chart and reloading it. But still no change.

```
<a onclick="gantt.clearAll()" href="javascript:void(0);">Clear</a>
<a onclick="gantt.load('./gantt_data', 'xml')" href="javascript:void(0);">Refresh</a>
```

I also tried moving the div block "gantt_here" to various other places above and below Laravel's template directives. It fails in all cases, except when this div block is outside (either above or below) the "app" div tag in "app.blade.php" which, of course, defeats the purpose I am trying to achieve.

My goal is to use this chart within Laravel's extended templating capabilities. But I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I just took the effort of setting this up and testing. Except for using the newer package as instructed (failing without this) everything else worked fine as per the tutorial. Even using partials and layouts worked fine without any issues. I used the javascript files from the sample project archive provided in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

After further troubleshooting, I discovered the problem. It turns out that in app.blade.php, I was loading the app.js at the bottom of the body tag. When I moved this up to the HTML header area, the data began to display properly.